# how to stop default behavior of onbeforeunload and do my own functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to handle the red close icon in the browser and tab close. I need to do some functionality on closing of the browser. But it should not effect the refresh and also how do I differentiate the browser close icon and tab close icon.

Comment: But I want to stop default behavior of onbeforeunload and do my own functionality...

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
// your code goes here 
}
```

Comment: I tried this. by default it is showing a pop up which is saying you want "leave this page" or "stay on this page" I dont need this pop up and i want show my own pop up in place of default. and it will work refresh also

Comment: dide replace the comment by showing the code to show your popup ?

Comment: with this we can just pass the text that will shown in the default pop up other than that we cant do anything

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to catch if a tab or the windows is closed. Anyway you can try to access the onunload or the onbeforeunload event.

Comment: I tried this. by default it is showing a pop up which is saying you want "leave this page" or "stay on this page" I dont need this pop up and i want show my own pop up in place of default. and it will work refresh also

Comment: It is not possible to edit this dialog. All you can do is add the message, as you already did. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: thanks PForseberg is there any way to stop this event on refresh of the page

Comment: can we prevent onbeforeunload?

Comment: If you return nothing, the dialog does not popup: window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        return;
};
On the other hand, that does nothing else, than if you would just not call the function ...